# Tkinter Frame Won't Center Properly (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, center

I have `small_frame` (filled in black) inside `big_frame`. I have used the `place()` method to center `small_frame` by setting `relx` to 0.5, but it's clearly still skewed right.

Placing by set coordinates does not work either as it is either skewed left or right.

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('950x587')

big_frame = LabelFrame(root, width=210, height=291)
big_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

small_frame = Frame(big_frame, width=198, height=123, bg='black')
small_frame.place(relx=0.5, y=64, anchor=CENTER)  # x=103 is it's coordinate equivalent

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measured it to the pixel. The `small-frame` is centered between the absolute boundaries of the `big-frame`. It is being placed perfectly.

You might be thrown off a bit because the `big-frame` itself is not symmetric; there is a 1-pixel thick white line on the `big-frame` that is on the inside of the darker gray line on the left side, but outside of it on the right side. This white line is part of the dimensions of the `big-frame`. You could say that the `big-frame` itself is causing the "skew" through an optical illusion.

Frankly, it's a difference of 1 pixel. If it's a serious issue, change the border of the `big-frame` in some way, or increase the `width` of the `big-frame` by 1 pixel.

Comment: You're right, it was big_frame causing it to look asymmetric. Changing its relief to 'solid' makes small_frame appear in the center.